# XHTML and code inside textareas

Tags: validation, xhtml

On a site of mine in which a textarea is used for submission, I have code that can appear something along the lines of the following:

```
<textarea><p>text</p></textarea>
```

When validating (XHTML 1.0 Transitional), this error arises,

```
line 88 column 50 - Error: document type does not allow element "p" here
```

If this is not a valid method, then what is expected?  I could do a workaround with an onload JavaScript event, but that seems needless.  Regardless this doesn't affect the output, but I'd rather my site validate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is there a reason you're trying to put a `<p>` within `<textarea>`? as you found out it's not valid. if it's for display purposes (ie, showing code) it should be translated:

```
<textarea>&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

beyond validation issues, allowing arbitrary tags (which are not properly encoded as above) to display can be a huge security issue. it's paramount to make sure any user supplied input has been properly sanitized before it is displayed.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking HTML entities wouldn't display within the textarea (dumb).  Converting the HTML entities to the characters, then all of them back seems to have do it :)

Answer (score 3):

Would a CDATA section be an option for you?

```
<textarea><![CDATA[
    <p>Blah</p>
]]></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in thinking your trying to make a  WYSIWYG editor, such as TinyMCE? What most seem to do is use HTML entities in the `textarea` and convert it to HTML via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the tags in the text area, and when you need new lines use \n  Otherwise use `&lt;p&gt;` and `&lt;/p&gt;` in the place of your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an onload function to replace starts and ends tags of the textarea content.

```
eg: replace < > with &lt; &gt;

<textarea cols="" rows="">&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

<p>text</p>

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function on the posted data

```
function clean_data($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $value = stripslashes($value); }
    $value = addslashes(htmlentities(trim($value)));
    $value = str_replace("\'", "&#39;", $value);
    $value = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $value);
    $value = str_replace(":", "&#58;", $value);
    return $value;
}
```