# Textarea display of special characters. Struts 1

Tags: java, html, jsp, encoding, struts

I'm having problems displaying some special characters within my Struts 1 application, specifically to **Textarea** fields, NOT normal Text fields. I pull out a bunch of text from a database, some of which contains special HTML characters, namely **'**, **<** and **>**

Before display, I have some Java formatter classes to convert those characters to something more HTML friendly. For example **'** which my formatter transcribes to **& #39;**

On display however, I basically get the raw **& #39;** displayed.

Does anyone know a way around this? Or why it only seems to happen with **Textarea**, as using a regular Text input displays the ' as expected.

My jsp page encoding is ISO-8859-1. I've tried it with UTF-8, but no luck

Comment: Text areas display whatever is put in them. If you're escaping it then it'll display as escaped. Don't escape it.

Comment: Kind of contradicts this item though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196097/xhtml-and-code-inside-textareas